# how do i solve this permission denied error when i run python manage.py startapp

Tags: python, django

am pretty new to django and i just installed VS code and python and django too. then in the VS terminal when i type python manage.py startapp base i get the error

```
bash: /c/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission denied.
```

how do i tackle this problem.
i don't think this is a VS issue, am suspecting its from my installation or something. i installed django in my desktop and it was successfull. what then could be denying it permission

Comment: It means console can't access the **python interpreter**. make sure the location is correct and path to the interpreter is in the PATH variable.

Comment: am lost. how do u mean please